# Mysql Join 2 tables very slow without adding other indexes

Tags: mysql, performance, select, join

Helllo
I have this 2 tables :

- recording_log(recording_id, lead_id ,length, filename ,location )
- vicidial_list(lead_id, phone_number )

when i put this query in the sql console , it seems very slow (> 5min)

```
SELECT vc.phone_number, vc.lead_id, rl.location, rl.filename FROM `recording_log` as rl 
INNER JOIN vicidial_list as vc ON vc.lead_id=rl.lead_id 
WHERE vc.phone_number="000021125454" aND length > "550";
```

This is whats i have in **EXPLAIN** :
[image]

i have index in `recording_log(lead_id)`
and in `vicidial_list(lead_id)`

```
CREATE TABLE recording_log (
    recording_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    filename varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
    lead_id int(9) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    user varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
    vicidial_id varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (recording_id), 
    KEY filename (filename), 
    KEY lead_id (lead_id), 
    KEY user (user), 
    KEY vicidial_id (vicidial_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3417340;

CREATE TABLE vicidial_list (
    lead_id int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    phone_number varchar(18) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    list_id bigint(14) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    PRIMARY KEY (lead_id), 
    KEY phone_number (phone_number), 
    KEY list_id (list_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3531081
```

Comment: How many rows do you have? five minutes seems rather unlikely here unless you have a huge table. Please post your table create statements and also indicate the number of rows

Comment: thnx for reply , i have > 3M rows and this show create table stat..CREATE TABLE `recording_log` (
 `recording_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `filename` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `lead_id` int(9) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `user` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `vicidial_id` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`recording_id`),
 KEY `filename` (`filename`),
 KEY `lead_id` (`lead_id`),
 KEY `user` (`user`),
 KEY `vicidial_id` (`vicidial_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3417340;

Comment: and this for vicidial_list ;   CREATE TABLE `vicidial_list` (
 `lead_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `phone_number` varchar(18) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `list_id` bigint(14) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`lead_id`),
 KEY `phone_number` (`phone_number`),
 KEY `list_id` (`list_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3531081

Comment: It's interesting that your CREATE TABLE statement does not show a length column which appears in your query :)

Answer (score 0):

The `EXPLAIN` and the `CREATE TABLEs` both indicate you have the best indexes, and the query should take much less than one second.

However...

Since you are using MyISAM (instead of InnoDB), writes can block reads such that the read can take a long time.  What else was running at the same time?

Perhaps the best solution is to `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB;`.  (Be sure to have a lot of extra disk space when doing it.)  You may as well do that for all of your tables.

[*More tips and caveats*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).